# Analytics: split-summarize records

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

Consider the following hypothetical accounting records for staff activities in a publishing company:

```
Name          Activity        Begin-date       End-date
---------------------------------------------------------
Hasan         Proofreading    2015-01-27       2015-02-09
Susan         Writing         2015-02-01       2015-02-15
Peter         Editing         2015-01-01       2015-02-21
Paul          Editing         2015-01-24       2015-01-30
Stefan        Proofreading    2015-01-08       2015-01-08
...
```

These represent activities that each person is doing, including the beginning and ending dates (inclusive dates). Let's say that this company's exec wants to know how many man-days were spent in different activities *for each month*. The desired report may look like this:

```
Month        Activity          Man-hours
----------------------------------------
2015-01      Proofreading      720
2015-01      Editing           1283
2015-01      Writing           473
2015-02      Proofreading      1101
2015-02      Editing           893
2015-02      Writing           573
...
```

Assuming python Pandas analytics framework, can we do this relying (mostly) on pandas' API, rather than doing a low level, "bit-by-bit" programming? The issue with this query is that the "begin" and "end" times of each record can straddle over several months (not just one month), so those records will need to be "split", or "exploded" into multiple records (each covering a period of one month), then we can use the usual "groupby & sum" aggregation to do the final reduction.

Having never been formally trained in SQL or database, I don't know if there is such a concept in data analytics, so I don't know the proper name. In Spark, I think this can be done, because RDD `flatMap` can return multiple elements out of a single element.

Thanks,
Wirawan

Answer (score 0):

First, create a dense long dataframe with each day between each begin date and end date. To do so, Pandas has `pd.date_range` that generate a `DatetimeIndex` from two dates. Assuming people dans work on weekends, let's use a business day frequency, but you can use any useful frequency for your case in it.

From this ranges we do a bit of reformatting with `stack` and some index reset. It leads to:

```
df =(df.set_index(['name', 'activity'])
       .apply(lambda r : pd.Series(pd.date_range(r['begindate'],r['enddate'], freq='B')), 
              axis=1)
       .stack()
       .rename('date')
       .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
       .reset_index())
Out[73]: 
      name      activity       date
0    Hasan  Proofreading 2015-01-27
1    Hasan  Proofreading 2015-01-28
2    Hasan  Proofreading 2015-01-29
3    Hasan  Proofreading 2015-01-30
4    Hasan  Proofreading 2015-02-02
..     ...           ...        ...
10   Susan       Writing 2015-02-02
11   Susan       Writing 2015-02-03
..     ...           ...        ...
```

Now you ca do your monthly aggregation. Convert the dates to monthly periods and group against it:

```
df.groupby(['activity',df.date.dt.to_period('M')]).size()
Out[97]: 
activity      date   
Editing       2015-01    27
              2015-02    15
Proofreading  2015-01     5
              2015-02     6
Writing       2015-02    10
```